# Composite columns and "IN" relation in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have the following column family in Cassandra for storing time series data in a small number of very "wide" rows:

```
CREATE TABLE data_bucket (
  day_of_year int,
  minute_of_day int,
  event_id int,
  data ascii,
  PRIMARY KEY (data_of_year, minute_of_day, event_id)
)
```

On the CQL shell, I am able to run a query such as this:

```
select * from data_bucket where day_of_year = 266 and minute_of_day = 244 
  and event_id in (4, 7, 11, 1990, 3433)
```

Essentially, I fix the value of the first component of the composite column name (minute_of_day) and want to select a non-contiguous set of columns based on the distinct values of the second component (event_id). Since the "IN" relation is interpreted as an equality relation, this works fine.

Now my question is, how would I accomplish the same type of composite column slicing programmatically and without CQL. So far I have tried the Python client pycassa and the Java client Astyanax, but without any success.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

EDIT:

I'm adding the describe output of the column family as seen through cassandra-cli. Since I am looking for a Thrift-based solution, maybe this will help.

```
ColumnFamily: data_bucket
  Key Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type
  Default column value validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AsciiType
  Cells sorted by: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.CompositeType(org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type,org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type)
  GC grace seconds: 864000
  Compaction min/max thresholds: 4/32
  Read repair chance: 0.1
  DC Local Read repair chance: 0.0
  Populate IO Cache on flush: false
  Replicate on write: true
  Caching: KEYS_ONLY
  Bloom Filter FP chance: default
  Built indexes: []
  Compaction Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy
  Compression Options:
    sstable_compression: org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor
```

Comment: Are you sure this query works in cassandra cqlsh? In cassandra IN operation is only supported on partition key and in your case event_id is mere clustering columns.

Comment: @abhi It certainly does work. My understanding is, the last component of the composite column can specify a range/slice of columns as long as all the previous components specify strict equality relations. Have a look here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/introduction-to-composite-columns-part-1

Comment: @abhi And here: http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#selectStmt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "IN"-type query in the Thrift API. You could perform a series of `get` queries for each composite column value (`day_of_year`, `minute_of_day`, `event_id`).

If your `event_id`s were sequential (and your question says they are not) you could perform a single `get_slice` query, passing in the range (e.g., `day_of_year`, `minute_of_day`, and range of `event_id`s). You could grab bunches of them in this way and filter the response programatically yourself (e.g., grab all data on the date with event ids between 4-3433). More data transfer, more processing on the client side so not a great option unless you really are looking for a range.

So, if you want to use "IN" with Cassandra you will need to switch to a CQL-based solution. If you are considering using CQL in python another option is [cassandra-dbapi2](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-dbapi2/). This worked for me:

```
import cql

# Replace settings as appropriate
host = 'localhost'
port = 9160
keyspace = 'keyspace_name'

# Connect
connection = cql.connect(host, port, keyspace, cql_version='3.0.1')
cursor = connection.cursor()
print "connected!"

# Execute CQL
cursor.execute("select * from data_bucket where day_of_year = 266 and minute_of_day = 244 and event_id in (4, 7, 11, 1990, 3433)")
for row in cursor:
  print str(row) # Do something with your data

# Shut the connection
cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

(Tested with Cassandra 2.0.1.)

Comment: It works in CQL, but as I mentioned in my question, I'm looking for a solution without it.

Comment: If you don't want to use CQL are you looking for a Thrift or CLI-based alternative? [Cassandra's own recommendation is to use CQL-based clients](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ClientOptions). The solution proposed will allow you to build any CQL-based query (the string passed to `cursor.execute`) and execute it programatically using the cassandra-dbapi2 client.

Comment: I have to integrate with an existing codebase that uses Astyanax without CQL. And while I could possibly push towards CQL, I am quite curious in figuring out how this works under the covers via Thrift.

Comment: Understood. It would be worth adding a CF/table definition in the question to CLI format. What about a wide row with a Composite column (either IntegerType,IntegerType,IntegerType or simply DateType,IntegerType)? I can augment my answer with a CLI formulation if that would help (I've just migrated from CLI [hector&pycassa] to CQL [datastax/cassandra-dbapi2] myself -it's painful but worth it in the long run imho).

Comment: Added the cli description of the column family. It would be a wide row with a composite column (int32, int32) name representing the minute_of_day and event_id, and an int32 key validator for the day_of_year.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil. Added a prefix to my answer, basically you'll be making a get request for each `event_id` using thrift. It's not the solution you're looking for I'm sure but there's no alternative that I can think of. Hope this is enough for you...

Comment: I suspected this would be the only way to go. Thanks for confirming. Must really look at moving the codebase to CQL.

Comment: cheers, fwiw, I use the [Datastax java-driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) for java and the [iconara cql-rb](https://github.com/iconara/cql-rb/) for ruby.